# Armour loss in underground cables

Tags: cables, power-engineering

What are sheath and armour loss in underground cables?How can these be prevented?

Comment: By using quality cables and protecting them from physical damage by various means. There must be books written on the subject of how to make underground cabling properly and up to local standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sheathed cables running AC have inductive coupling to the sheath and armor, which induce eddy currents leading to parasitic losses. More here: https://mycableengineering.com/knowledge-base/cable-sheath-and-armour-loss.

The fill also absorbs some of this coupling resulting in further losses.

High-voltage DC (HVDC) was developed to counteract these losses. HVDC avoids eddy currents in the sheath/armor and capacitive losses, as well as skin effect in the cable.